# ASP.NET MVC save a lot of field from the UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have in the UI a lot of field, when I post the from to "MyController", action "Insert"

I have to do this :

```
public ActionResult Insert(string fieldA, string FieldB, int age, .....)
{
}
```

Is there another way to get value from the form ? (using ASP.NET MVC3) I have around 20 fields to save ....

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make use of a `ViewModel` instead through the concept called Model binding.

Here is a sample that I have used:

```
public ActionResult Create()  {
   return View(new MyCreateViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
    try
    {
        db.Save(viewModel);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
        return View();
    }
}
```

And the view model would look like this:

```
public class MyCreateViewModel {
   public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

With this, I am using a strongly typed view that uses MyCreateViewModel and on the view I make use of `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyProperty)` for editing the fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a input model, which basically is a POCO with properties for each field. Something like this:

```
class InsertInputModel
{
    public string Field1 {get; set; }
    public string Field2 {get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then you just accept a InputModel in your controller action, like so:

```
public ActionResult Insert(InsertInputModel model)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. In the UI page I display some data from a model. The Html.Textbox where the value are show don't have the same name than the property of the Model. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Combine them into a model, or just take in the FormCollection

```
public ActionResult Insert(MyCustomModel model)
{
    // model.FieldA
}    

public ActionResult Insert(FormCollection form)
{
    var fieldA = form["fieldA"];
}
```

Comment: Option 1 if they can logically grouped into a model, otherwise, simply use FormCollection .